# how to read the browser's address bar parameters in cgi-script (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tomcat, cgi-bin

I want to get the parameters of the address bar of the browser 
http://localhost:8080/WebApplication3/cgi-bin/servlet.js?number1=1&number2=2
for example, return from the server "number1 = 1"
I use Apache Tomchat 9.0.1, node.js 8.9.1 , NetBeans 8.2. I configured scripts Python http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/cgi-bin/servlet.py?Number1=1, PHP, Java, everything works well
my code

```
console.log('Content-Type: text/html');
console.log('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
console.log('');
console.log('qqqqqqqqqqqqqq');

//var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);//not work
//console.log(urlParams.toString());//not work
//console.log(window..protocol);//not work
//console.log('dfgsdfgs'+location.pathname.toString());//not work
//console.log(window.location.hash);//not work
//console.log(window.location.host);//not work
//if (window.location.search) {//not work
//    console.log('yes');//not work
//}else {//not work
//    console.log('no');//not work
//}    
//console.log(window.location.search.toString());//not work
//console.log(window.location.search);//not work
```

open code works fine, gives the client "qqqqqqqqqqqqqq", comment lines do not work

I ask not to offer to create a server in a node, since I want to use apache tomcat
I've studied the node-сgi, I do not understand how to use it, there it is suggested to use files .nd, .jss, to fix .htaccess. Is there really no simple solution of the type:
`$ _GET ['number1'];` (php) or

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage ()
print int (form ["number1"]. value) + int (form ["number2"]. value)
```

in the python?
example php

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
// put your code here
$num1 = $_GET['number1'];
$num2 = $_GET['number2'];
$sum = $num1 + $num2;
echo $sum;
```

example python

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
print                               # blank line, end of headers
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print int(form["number1"].value) + int(form["number2"].value)
```

thank you for any help

Comment: What scripting language is the second part of this question in? Python?

Comment: does not work native javascript, runs php, python

Comment: `//var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);//not work` - in what way does this "not work" - should work, unless you're using internet exploder of course ... oh, wait, is that first block of code in NODE?

Comment: If you're using Node, it doesn't have a CGI mode. With [Express](http://expressjs.com) you just stand up a full HTTP server and interface with that directly, or put that behind an application HTTP/HTTPS proxy.